# What is this "Default Profile"?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I was poking around my performance settings tabs and clicked on one that showed users. It has the single account that was set up (as Admin) and a Default user account.

I am curious to know why it is there. Does it serve some purpose?

[image: default]

Comment: @Ramhound - It is in fact my wife's home laptop. The default profile is present if I go to C:\Users as well, just never noticed it before. Here it is accessible, but grey in contrast to the other account.

Comment: The reply to the question found here: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/137223-45-whats-users-default-user gives a great explanation of how the "Default Profile" can be used. As its name implies, that profile can be configured to hold default settings for all new users added to the computer. You make one change, all future users will inherit that change. You can also read more about profiles here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [default profile](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973289), as it suggests, is the profile that a new account created on that computer defaults to - which means whatever is on the Desktop, Pictures, etc. folder will be transferred over to all new accounts on that computer. You can also use the answer to [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/how-do-i-customize-the-default-user-profile-in/54c135b0-fa37-499b-9e2f-ac90df19bb67) post to customize default profiles.

It is hidden by default, but this profile resides in `C:\Users\Default` - if you enable the showing of hidden files/folders you are able to modify what a new account contains by default.

Answer (score 0):

New profiles are created (when a new user account is created, for example) by copying the Default Profile to the new one.
 
This default profile also can be modified to match your preferences for new users.